# How to use cin with unknown input types?

Tags: c++

I have a C++ program which needs to take user input. The user input will either be two ints (for example: 1 3) or it will be a char (for example: s).

I know I can get the twos ints like this:

```
cin >> x >> y;
```

But how do I go about getting the value of the cin if a char is input instead? I know cin.fail() will be called but when I call cin.get(), it does not retrieve the character that was input.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: use `templates` http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::getline` to read the input into a string, then use `std::istringstream` to parse the values out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in c++11. This solution is robust, will ignore spaces.

This is compiled with clang++-libc++ in ubuntu 13.10. Note that gcc doesn't have a full regex implementation yet, but you could use [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) as an alternative.

EDIT: Added negative numbers handling.

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>


using namespace std;

int main() {
   regex pattern(R"(\s*(-?\d+)\s+(-?\d+)\s*|\s*([[:alpha:]])\s*)");

   string input;
   smatch match;

   char a_char;
   pair<int, int> two_ints;
   while (getline(cin, input)) {
      if (regex_match(input, match, pattern)) {
         if (match[3].matched) {
            cout << match[3] << endl;
            a_char = match[3].str()[0];
         }
         else {
            cout << match[1] << " " << match[2] << endl;
            two_ints = {stoi(match[1]), stoi(match[2])};
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: If the integers can be negative, this would not work.